# Looping through a JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I got a JSON file generated by a form, which has a structure like this :

```
[{"r1":"9","r2":"","r3":"3","r4":"10","r5":"","msg":"Integer tempor ullamcorper urna, at lacinia lectus sodales et. Pellentesque ac ornare justo. "},
{"r1":"4","r2":"7","r3":"","r4":"8","r5":"7","msg":"Integer tempor ullamcorper urna, at lacinia lectus sodales et. "}]
```

I need to perform stats on the numbers saved in (r1 to r5) and display the messages (msg)

I'm using two fixed loops to recreate arrays with these 2 differents content type

```
for (i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
    results.push([
                   +data[i]['r1'],
                   +data[i]['r2'],
                   +data[i]['r3'],
                   +data[i]['r4'],
                   +data[i]['r5']
                ]);
 }


 for (i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
     messages.push([
                    data[i]['msg']
                  ]);
  }
```

I wonder if there is a better way to loop through to the number values, because from time to time this form will have more or less number fiels (eg r1 to r15, I d'like not to be obliged to manually change my code everytime.

Using date[0].length dosnt help, I thought it was possible to count the number of objects in every {}

Many thanks for your help, I'm a newbie witj JSON and Array.

Comment: FYI - json does support other data types than just strings as values. http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1):

Use `for in` loop inside your initial loop:

```
for (i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
    for (var key in data[i]) {
        if (data[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && key != "msg")
             results.push(data[i][key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work, now I got an unique Array with every numbers one after another like this [9,0,3,10...], I can't compute operation with (eg r1+r1, r2+r2, ...)